# Question based on Number Systems sequence

Tags: number-theory

A sequence of $4$ digits, when considered as a number in base $10$ is four times the number it represents in base $6$. What is the sum of the digits of the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, the answer is *8*.

$1232$ in decimal, or $1232_6 = 308$.